# How to use a Batch file to set PATH and then input commands normally?

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt

I'm setting up an external hard drive with portable apps, and there are some CLI tools that I'd like to easily access.

I've done it before but I forgot how; basically, I have a file which sets the PATH variable for all the required CLI programs, and then allows me to use the command prompt normally.

How do I do this without having to run the file from another command prompt, but by double clicking the Batch file?

Comment: You can't, unless you're wanting to change them globally and permanently. Changes made in the batch file that was double clicked to execute will not affect the open command prompt where you're running your CLI tools.

Comment: @KenWhite I've definitely done it before successfully, I just can't remember how and was hoping someone here did.

Comment: You cannot change the PATH in one command session by double-clicking a batch file that opens another command session. You can change them in the batch file in which you're going to run your CLI tools, but not in a separate batch file that is going to be double-clicked separately. If you remember doing it before successfully, your memory is failing you. :-) You can change them globally before you launch your CLI prompt either manually or using SETX, but that will be a global change that affects not only your command session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your command line tools are in a folder named `CLiTools` next to the batch-file, then you could have 2 lines as the batch-file content.

```
@set "path=%path%;%~dp0CLiTools"
@cmd
```

You can double click the batch-file, it will open `cmd` with the modified setting of `%path%` and you can enter commands as you would normally do. If you have i.e. `xyz.exe` in the `CLiTools` folder, then you can type `xyz` at the current command prompt and will be recognized as a command.

The changed environment applies to the current child `cmd` session that inherited the environment.

`%~dp0` is the drive and path of argument 0 which is the drive and path to the batch-file in this case.

Comment: Ahh this is it exactly! So simple, I'm surprised I didn't try it. I'll try it out as soon as I can. Thank you.